# What Kind of Label to use

Tags: iphone, ios, text, cocos2d-iphone, uilabel

I am creating a tutorial scene for my game where I have to use lots of text. 
What would be the best Label option to use.

I have tried CCLabelTTF, its good, I could use multi line and people recommended not to use it.

I tried to use glyph designer but I could not use long text (goes out of the screen) and multi line.

My screen looks like this

How to Play Game

1. something something do this do that and again do this do that
2. something something do this
3. something something do this do that
4. something something do this do that and again do this do that

Comment: there's no problem using CCLabelTTF, as long as you don't keep changing the label's string it's just as fast as a CCSprite of the same size

Answer (score 1):

Use UITextView. Turn off scrolling and editable.